# What kind of wiring/switch to use for gas fireplace switch?

Tags: wiring, fireplace

I have a gas fireplace with a remote control plugged into an electrical outlet hidden below the fireplace unit. The remote control is old and not working, and I had thought about wiring up a switch instead by wiring the switch in place of the remote's leads. According to a fireplace tech, the remote box just acts as a short circuit between the leads.

Also there are [other questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37877/what-kind-of-wall-switch-is-needed-for-a-natural-gas-fireplace-to-ignite-consist) that mention needing specific milli-volt type switches.

Can I use normal romex/wire and 120V switch or is there something specific to high-heat situations and/or small currents?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives to a 120V light switch:

1. A good quality sealed gold plated electronic toggle switch.  There's a lot of different kinds.
2. A smart relay switch.  EG ZWave or whatever you want.  About $40, which is more than a bit of wire and a cheap light switch, but much less than a new fireplace remote and you would then have remote control from your phone and would not need to install a wall box as it would all go under the fireplace instead of the existing remote.   Not a regular smart light switch, that would zap your fireplace with 120V but a "relay" or also called "dry contact" switch.

And ... by FAR the best thing about Option 2 is that combined with a taught Alexa skill you could simulate [The Clapper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYKV_la8VJQ&t=4s).   Instant romance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. It really depends on the switch, old mercury silent switches I would say absolutely, why is there a difference?

Some snap switches have a contact resistance is two high to work on millivolt gas valves. So it is possible that a quality switch will work but some may not work. Now the even worse thing to warn you it may work today but not work in 2 weeks or when you really need the heat.

There is a trick that may clean the contacts if it works then quits or doesn’t  work the first time, try turning the switch on and off a dozen times this may clean the contacts enough to work.

So a light switch may work but not all will and the reason they don’t work is usually high contact resistance.